# Error Building Gatsby Site with PostCSS and TailwindCSS

Tags: reactjs, frontend, gatsby, tailwind-css, postcss

I might be a First Grader in this Coding World so please spare me if the solution to this question is obvious.

I am creating a Gatsby Site with TailwindCSS and had set it up after watching a YouTube Video. Everything is working fine in the development mode where I was working the entire part of 02 weeks.

I've setup the Gatsby Project with Contentful, PostCSS, and other standard image, head and manifest plugins.

I followed the guide https://medium.com/@mikeeeeeeey/create-react-app-tailwind-css-feat-postcss-631d9e33ba8c for setting up tailwind in my gatsby project with JIT and Purge.

For Reference, this is the Tailwind Config File

```
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
        colors: {
          blue: {
            50: '#EDFAFD',
            100: '#CAF0F8',
            200: '#ADE8F4',
            300: '#90E0EF',
            400: '#48CAE4',
            500: '#00B4D8',
            600: '#0096C7',
            700: '#0077B6',
            800: '#023E8A',
            900: '#03045E',
          },
        },
      ringWidth: ['hover', 'active', 'focus'],
      fontFamily: {
        'sans': ['Inter'],
        'mono': ['Roboto Mono'],
      },
      
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      fill: ['hover', 'focus'],
      stroke: ['hover', 'focus'],
      fontWeight: ['hover', 'focus', 'active'],
      textColor: ['hover', 'focus', 'active'],
      ringWidth: ['hover', 'active'],
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

This is my PostCSS config file

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
    ],
};
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "kabira-mobility",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Kabira Mobility",
  "author": "sagarsiwach",
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "postcss src/styles/styles.css -o src/index.css",
    "watch:css": "postcss src/styles/styles.css -o src/index.css -w",
    "develop": "npm run watch:css & gatsby develop",
    "start": "npm run watch:css & gatsby develop",
    "build": "npm run build:css && gatsby build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.4.0",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.3",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.2.0",
    "gatsby": "^3.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud": "^2.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^1.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-postcss": "^4.11.0",
    "gatsby-source-contentful": "^5.11.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^3.11.0",
    "postcss": "^8.3.6",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "swiper": "^6.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.1",
    "postcss-cli": "^8.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.7"
  }
}
```

and finally my gatsby config

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    siteUrl: "https://www.yourdomain.tld",
    title: "Kabira Mobility",
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-contentful",
      options: {
        accessToken: "#######MY Contentful Access Token########",
        spaceId: "#####My Contentful SpaceID######",
      },
    },
    "gatsby-plugin-postcss",
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`, // Needed for dynamic images
    "gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud",
  ],
};
```

This setup was working perfectly on the development mode. However, now I'm in the building stage but faced the following issue

```
warn warn - You have enabled the JIT engine which is currently in preview.
warn warn - Preview features are not covered by semver, may introduce breaking changes, and can change at any time.
⠙ Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles
/Users/sagarsiwach/Desktop/gatsby/kabira-august/node_modules/yoga-layout-prebuilt/yoga-layout/build/Release/nbind.js:53
        throw ex;
        ^

DataCloneError: function destructLexErrorInfo() {
          // remove cyclic references added to error info:
          // info....<omitted>... } could not be cloned.
    at reportError (/Users/sagarsiwach/Desktop/gatsby/kabira-august/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/threadChild.js:100:32)
    at reportClientError (/Users/sagarsiwach/Desktop/gatsby/kabira-august/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/threadChild.js:84:10)
Emitted 'error' event on Worker instance at:
    at Worker.[kOnErrorMessage] (node:internal/worker:297:10)
    at Worker.[kOnMessage] (node:internal/worker:308:37)
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> (node:internal/worker:211:57)
    at MessagePort.[nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:461:20)
    at MessagePort.exports.emitMessage (node:internal/per_context/messageport:23:28)
Sagars-MBP:kabira-august sagarsiwach$
```

I tried googling this, but did not get any answers that could fix this issue. I've then tried the following solutions

1. Recreated another Gatsby Directory and manually copy-pasting the files and installing dependency step by step. All worked fine until this PostCSS process thus determining the cause.
2. done this process twice and changed the tailwind installation method without any change in the error.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue.

Thanks very much kind stranger for looking at this post and providing a solution

Cheers!

Comment: There is some issue with `gatsby-plugin-postcss`. Downgrade its version to 4.10.0 inside your `package.json`  and then run `npm install` . After that try rebuilding your project.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow just following the [official tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/gatsby) didn't work. I had to add `postcss.config.js` at the root of my project with the following code.

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
  tailwindcss: {},
  autoprefixer: {},
 }
}
```

```
// These are the package versions
"gatsby": "^5.4.0"
"gatsby-plugin-postcss": "^6.4.0",
"postcss": "^8.4.21",
"autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
"tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your PostCSS configuration should look like:

```
module.exports = () => ({
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss")],
})
```

Check the [Tailwind + Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/tailwind-css/) integration for further details.